# how to run a jar file from a matlab code?

Tags: java, matlab, jar

If I have a `.jar` file that takes two command line arguments. How can I call it from a Matlab `.m` file?
I can call the jar file from the command line like this:

> jar -jar art.jar ex.xls 0

Comment: You probably meant: `java -jar art.jar ex.xls 0`.

Comment: yes this what I meant.

Answer (score 6):

You can use system() function. e.g.:

```
[status result] = system('java -jar art.jar ex.xls 0');
```

If you need to pass variables as parameters, you have to convert them to strings and then concatenate them (with space as separator). e.g.:

```
jarfile = 'art.jar';
xlsfile = 'ex.xls';
n = 0;
commandtext = ['java -jar ' jarfile ' ' xlsfile ' ' num2str(n)];
system(commandtext);
```